# google map api without refresh

Tags: google-maps

i need help with google map

I wanna without refresh map change marker

i get data from mysql and create marker

my file:

> function initialize(){
>
> var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.472627, 23.15918);
>
> var geocoder;
>      var map;
>      var markersArray = [];
>      var infos = [];
>
> var myOptions = {
>           zoom: 8,
>           center: latlng,
>            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>      };
>
> var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
>
> var encodedString;
>      var stringArray = [];
>
> encodedString = document.getElementById("encodedString").value;
>      stringArray = encodedString.split("****");
>
> var x;
>      for (x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x = x + 1){
>
> var addressDetails = [];
>
> addressDetails = stringArray[x].split(",");
>
> var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[0], addressDetails[1]);
>      console.log(lat);
>      console.log(addressDetails[0], addressDetails[1]);
>
> ```
> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
> map: map,
> position: lat,
> icon: addressDetails[2],
> title: "Atnaujinta: "+addressDetails[3]+""
>
>             });
>       }
>     }setInterval('updateMap()', 10000);
>         </script>
>
>     </head>
>     <?php 
>     //get data form mysql
>     mysql_connect('localhost', 'adena_root', 'gintariukas1');
>     mysql_select_db('adena_nav');
>
>     $encodedString = "";
>     $x = 0;
>
>     $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT X,Y,marker,data FROM nav");
>
>     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql, MYSQL_NUM)){
>         if ( $x == 0 ){
>              $separator = "";
>         }else{
>           $separator = "****";
>         }
>
>       $encodedString = $encodedString.$separator.
>         "".$row[0].
>         ",".$row[1].
>         ",".$row[2].
>       ",".$row[3];
>         $x = $x + 1;
>
>
>     }
>     ?>
>     <body onload="initialize()">
>     <input type="hidden" id="encodedString" name="encodedString" value="<?php echo $encodedString; ?>" />
>
>     <div id="map_canvas"></div>
>     </body>
>     </html>
> ```

maybe someone knows?:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using AJAX. First create a separate page that will display your map data in JSON format then fetch them in JavaScript to display them to the map. Here's a nice tutorial although it uses Google Maps v2, you can simple just change them to v3 code.

[AJAX Storing and Retrieving Points – Tutorial](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-ajax-php-mysql)